# Rewriting Apache Spark Scala into PySpark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

Community, I'm not familiar with Scala and not so great with PySpark. However, I'm much less familiar with Scala and therefore was hoping if someone could let me know if someone could help me re-write the following Apache Spark Scala to PySpark.

If you're going to ask what I have done so far to help myself, I'm going to honestly say very little, as I'm still in the early days of coding.

So, if you can help re-code the following into PySpark, or put me on the right path so that I can re-code it myself, that would be very helpful

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

def readParquet(basePath: String): DataFrame = {
  val parquetDf = spark
  .read
  .parquet(basePath)
  return parquetDf
}

def num(df: DataFrame): Int = {
  val numPartitions = df.rdd.getNumPartitions
  return numPartitions
}


def ram(size: Int): Int = {
  val ramMb = size
  return ramMb
}

def target(size: Int): Int = {
  val targetMb = size
  return targetMb
}


def dp(): Int = {
  val defaultParallelism  = spark.sparkContext.defaultParallelism
  return defaultParallelism
}

def files(dp: Int, multiplier: Int, ram: Int, target: Int): Int = {
  val maxPartitions = Math.max(dp * multiplier, Math.ceil(ram / target).toInt)
  return maxPartitions
}


def split(df: DataFrame, max: Int): DataFrame = {
  val repartitionDf = df.repartition(max)
  return repartitionDf
}

def writeParquet(df: DataFrame, targetPath: String) {
  return df.write.format("parquet").mode("overwrite").save(targetPath)
}

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("spark-repartition-optimizer-app").getOrCreate()
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 2001) // example
val parquetDf = readParquet("/blogs/source/airlines.parquet/")
val numPartitions = num(parquetDf)
val ramMb = ram(6510) // approx. df cache size
val targetMb = target(128) // approx. partition size (between 50 and 200 mb)
val defaultParallelism = dp()
val maxPartitions = files(defaultParallelism, 2, ramMb, targetMb)
val repartitionDf = split(parquetDf, maxPartitions)
writeParquet(repartitionDf, "/blogs/optimized/airlines.parquet/")
```

Comment: I would start searching for the methods here in `pyspark.sql` module and the rdd ones from `pyspark.rdd.RDD` documentation. For example you can search for term "parquet" from `pyspark.sql` module documentation and find out what your `readParquet` function is doing. Links: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html and https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.1/api/python/pyspark.rdd.RDD-class.html

Comment: @eemilk, thanks for reaching out. I guess what you're saying is that it's not easy to re-code Scala to PySpark unless you're proficient in both languages, correct?

Comment: I have not programmed with scala but those functions look easy enough to re-write to python and what comes to pyspark -> the syntax is almost exactly like with spark. It's just API to control spark, so searching the spark methods e.g. `repartition` from `pyspark.sql` module you can read what it does and use it in python with pyspark correctly. But definitely you need to know something about python e.g. functions, looping etc.

Comment: @eemilk, thanks again for reaching out. I agree, its quite easy. I have just come across a section of the scala code tha is proving difficult to convert to PySpark. I keep on getting the error message: name 'math' is not defined 
When I run the following function
```def files(dp, multiplier, ram, target):
  maxPartitions = math.max(dp * multiplier, math.ceil(ram / target).toInt)
  return maxPartitions```
Any thoughts?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_math.asp

Comment: @eemilk, the answer to the math issue was simply import math module

Answer (score 0):

I simply need to re-code the Scala code to PySpark myself.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed by including the following module in pyspark.

```
import module
```